# Multiple Job (j3)

Tags: jobs, gnu-make, sh

I am trying to run a GNU make file with multiple jobs.

When I try executing '    make.exe -r -j3', the receive the following to errors:

```
make.exe: Do not specify -j or --jobs if sh.exe is not available.
make.exe: Resetting make for single job mode.
```

Do I have to add '    $(SH) -c' somewhere in the makefile? If so, where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Job (j3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510398/multiple-job-j3)

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that `make` cannot find `sh.exe`.  The file names indicate you are probably on CygWin.  I would investigate setting the `PATH` to include the location of `sh.exe`, or defining the value of `SHELL` to the name (or, even, full path) of your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Windows (more specifically, in the "windows" shell?). If you are, you might want to read this:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel

more specifically:

On MS-DOS, the ‘-j’ option has no effect, since that system doesn't support multi-processing.

Once again, assuming you're running on windows, you should get MinGW or CygWin

Comment: Just having the DLL won't be enough. Just download "the full" Cygwin environment, which will come with the bash shell wrapper, then you can invoke multiple jobs on make in that shell